# WSO2 rest api to fetch apps list redirects to login page

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have a running instance of WSO2 on kubernetes. I need to call the rest APIs for listing and exporting the apps, which are like below:
https://<base_URL>/t/<tenant_domain>/api/server/v1/

I have created an ingress rule for /t, but when I try any API with above format, the call gets redirected to the login page.

Sample API:
curl -X GET "https://<base_URL>/t/carbon.super/api/server/v1/applications?limit=30&offset=0" -H "accept: application/json"

As you can see in below screenshot from postman, the call gets redirected to the management UI

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hyjpo.png)

Please let me know your comments on this

Thanks

Comment: I guess you are trying to invoke an API. So this API traffic should route to 8243/8280 default ports of the API Manager. It seems your request is going to 9443 port. Hence the redirection.

Comment: Did you check the http_access log of WSO2IS, whether a request has come to correct endpoint (/t/carbon.super/api/server/v1/applications)?

Also note that this API is available in 5.10.0 and 5.11.0 only https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/application-rest-api/

Comment: Thanks @Sajith the problem was regarding the version. We are using 5.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the information in the comments, the issue is that these APIs are not available in the particular version (5.8.0) used. Most of the management REST APIs (except for SCIM) were introduced to the product in 5.10.0 or 5.11.0. Therefore it is good to refer to the documentation for relevant product versions to avoid confusion.